# GTK timer/alarm app. Event to trigger loop exit

Tags: gtk

I'm trying to make an alarm/timer app and, at least in my head, it requires some sort of loop to display the current time in a `label`. Regardless of how I would conduct the 'counting' part, I'd still have to actively display the time through the `label` in a loop.

My problem is that... It doesn't work... I mean I can't exit the loop through my `Stop` button since the program is preoccupied with displaying with the `label`.

How should I approach this? GTK just refuses to interact while on a loop.

Comment: A tight loop to do something as trivial as updating the current time? Surely just scheduling a timer to go off in, say, 0.25s and doing the display update once then (before rescheduling) would let you have accurate enough timings? [Done as comment; I don't know how to write this with GTK as my expertise is with other toolkits.]

Comment: Oh yea, now that you mention it I remember a function somewhere along the lines of that. Finding it is gonna be an adventure though.

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking for a simple timer to achieve this then you can have a look at [`g_timeout_add`](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.28/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-timeout-add). [Here](http://pastebin.com/aHL79VDQ) is a minimal program to prove its working in a over simplistic case. But as mentioned in [the developer page](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.28/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-timeout-add) it can be delayed due to event handling and should not be relied on for precise timing.
Hope this helps!